Understanding correlated and hierarchical effects models in meta-analysis
I am doing a three-level meta-analysis, and I want to compare a three-level correlated and hierarchical effects model where effects are nested between-studies to a two-level model where variance at the study level is constrained to 0.
Initially, I was using the below simple three-level random effects model:
model <-                   rma.mv(yi = es, 
                           V = var, 
                           slab = study,
                           data = depression,
                           random = ~ 1 | study/es.id, 
                           test = "t", 
                           method = "REML")

And comparing it to this mixed effects model.
model.reduced <-           rma.mv(yi = es, 
                           V = var, 
                           slab = study,
                           data = depression,
                           random = ~ 1 | study/es.id, 
                           test = "t", 
                           method = "REML",
                           sigma2 = (0,NA))

anova(model, model.reduced)

This enables me to understand how the model fitness changes as a function of clustering the effects. Straightforward so far.
However, since then I have fitted the above model as a correlated hierarchical model as below (V.6), which will then allow me to further fit it with robust variance estimation andavoid model misspecification. I have done this by changing the variance input to an imputed_variance_matrix derived using the ClubSandwich package in R. Please see below for an example:
V.6 <- with(depression, 
           impute_covariance_matrix(vi = var,
           cluster = study,
           r = rho))

I now am using below model [che.model.6], however I cannot compare it to the reduced model [model.reduced] because the covariances are not equal between the two models. Is it problematic, using the same logic as above, to compare the che.model.6 to che.model.60 in order to compare the difference in heterogeneity when variance is constrained at the study-cluster level to 0.
che.model.6 <- rma.mv(yi =es,
                      V = V.6,
                      random = ~ 1 | study/es.id,
                      data = depression,
                      sparse = TRUE)

che.model.60 <- rma.mv(yi =es,
                      V = V.6,
                      random = ~ 1 | study/es.id,
                      data = depression,
                      sparse = TRUE,
                      sigma2 =  c(0, NA))

anova(che.model.6, che.model.60)

Does this second ANOVA fulfil the same function as the first one with random effects models? Or does RVE, e.g:
coef_test(che.model.6, 
          vcov = "CR2")

essentially fulfil the same function for my CHE model as the anova does for my random effects three level model?
Thank you for your help.

Yes, anova(model, model.reduced) and anova(che.model.6, che.model.60) serve the same purpose - they provide likelihood ratio tests for the study-level variance component (i.e., the 'between-study' variance).
An interesting question is whether the three-level correlated and hierarchical effects model (che.model.6) fits better than the standard three-level model (model). While anova() won't be able to give you a LRT to compare these models, there are still some possible ways of comparing them. First, you can compare these models based on their information criteria with fitstats(model, che.model.6). Moreover, one could consider doing the LRT manually here. One can argue that che.model.6 has one more parameter (rho, the correlation of the sampling errors that you used in impute_covariance_matrix), and hence one could use a chi-square distribution with one degree of freedom for the LRT. This would be:
fs <- fitstats(model, che.model.6)
X2 <- fs[2,1] - fs[2,2]
fmtt(X2, df=1, pval=pchisq(X2, df=1, lower.tail=FALSE), tname="X2")


Many, many thanks, Wolfgang. Not just for your helpful answer here, but also for the sum of your contribution to meta-analytic studies.

And thanks for your question. This just inspired me to add the possibility to conduct the LRT in some special cases 'manually' using the anova() function. If you install the 'devel' version of metafor, then anova(che.model.6, model, df=1) should now work. Note that one has to specify the degrees of freedom manually.

Thank you again. I have run the LRT using the code you have provided, and I will try your refined solution now. Here is the output: [1] X2(df = 1) = -1.7864, p-val = 1.0000. The CHE model provides a slight reduction in information criteria but not significantly so. A question I have about CHE models is whether they should be selected even when they are not significantly better in terms of model fit but I know the effects to be correlated (they come from the same sample).

Double-check the order of the models. I would expect a positive chi-square statistic. In any case, I don't know how well this test performs, so I would focus more on substantive considerations and not so much on the results of this test.
